# Why is UIControlState a Struct and not an Enum?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a bit confused by how UIControlState operates. Specifically, if I look at the following example:

```
sender.setTitle("NewTitle", for: UIControlState.normal)
```

I understand that this sets the title for the Button's (Sender's) normal state. I would have expected .normal to be an Enum value of the type UIControlState, but instead learned that it was a struct with constants. First question:

1. If the purpose is to just pass a state, why wasn't this defined as an enum with .normal as one of the cases?

Secondly, when I look at the documentation for UIStateControl, all I see are definitions of "constants," e.g.:

```
static var normal: UIControlState
```

Second/Third question:

2. Why are the "constants" for UIStateControl defined with "var" and not "let?"
3. How is UIControlState's static property defined as type "UIControlState?" Isn't that recursive?

Comment: I am not sure about this  but if you see struct `public struct UIControlState : OptionSet`  `OptionSet` is RowRepresntable , so .normal is fine for it , Might  @Paulw11 may help in this

Comment: @Paulw11 It's not due to any limitation of Obj-C; enumerations defined with the `NS_ENUM` macro are imported into Swift as `enum`s. It's purely due to the fact that `UIControlState` is fundamentally not an `enum`; it's an option set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is UIControlState a Struct and not an Enum?

`UIControlState` is *fundamentally* not an enumeration. An enumeration is an "OR" type.

```
enum Foo {
    case a, b, c
}

var f = Foo.a
f = .b
f = .c
```

So, in the above example, `f` can hold `.a` **or** `.b` **or** `.c`.

But that's not the case with `UIControlState`; it's an *option set*. An option set can hold a set of one or more cases. It is therefore an "AND" type, and we usually implement them with a `struct` that conforms to the [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) protocol.

```
struct Bar : OptionSet {

    let rawValue: Int

    // Note that the raw values are unique powers of two.
    // Each bit represents a flag determining if a given case is present.
    static let a = Bar(rawValue: 1) // 001
    static let b = Bar(rawValue: 2) // 010
    static let c = Bar(rawValue: 4) // 100
}

var b = Bar.a    // .a but not .b or .c
b = [.a, .b]     // .a and .b, but not .c
b = [.c, .a, .b] // .a and .b and .c
```

So, you can see in the above example, `b` can hold any set of `.a`, `.b` and `.c`.

And that's the same with `UIControlState`; we can for example talk about a control state of being focused *and* highlighted:

```
let controlState: UIControlState = [.highlighted, .focused]
```

If it were an `enum`, we could only talk about whether a control was in *one* specific state, such as only highlighted *or* only focussed. But that's not a correct model, because controls can be in multiple different states at once.

Also it's worth noting that with `UIControlState`, the [`.normal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolstate/1618233-normal) case is equivalent to an empty set of options `[]`; it means "not highlighted or focussed or selected or disabled or ...".

> Secondly, when I look at the documentation for UIStateControl, all I
>   see are definitions of "constants," e.g.:
>
> ```
> static var normal: UIControlState
> ```

That's not quite accurate. The `UIControlState` declaration in the auto-generated Swift header looks like this:

```
public struct UIControlState : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)


    public static var normal: UIControlState { get }

    public static var highlighted: UIControlState { get } // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set

    public static var disabled: UIControlState { get }

    public static var selected: UIControlState { get } // flag usable by app (see below)

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    public static var focused: UIControlState { get } // Applicable only when the screen supports focus

    public static var application: UIControlState { get } // additional flags available for application use

    public static var reserved: UIControlState { get } // flags reserved for internal framework use
}
```

You'll note the `{ get }` at the end. This means that they are just *read only* properties. How they are actually implemented (as `let` constants, `var` read-only computed properties etc.) is a pure implementation detail.

In this case, `UIControlState` is defined in UIKit with the `NS_OPTIONS` macro, which Swift [imports in as an](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID169) `OptionSet` conforming structure with each option value being a static read-only property.

> How is UIControlState's static property defined as type "UIControlState?" Isn't that recursive?

No, it's not recursive at all. Remember, they're `static` properties, and as such are nothing more than global variables namespaced to `UIControlState` (and they don't even need to have storage; they could be computed, although, again that's an implementation detail).

If they were *instance* stored properties, then it would indeed be recursive. But they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is UIControlState a Struct and not an Enum?

Because [UIControlEvents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents) is related to the [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) framework which has been built using *Objective-C*, means that it has nothing to do with the Swift enums.

> If the purpose is to just pass a state, why wasn't this defined as an
>   enum with .normal as one of the cases?

Nevertheless, `UIControlEvents` struct conforms to [*OptionSet*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) protocol, which is part of the Swift programming language; The purpose of conforming to the `OptionSet` is to representing [*bit mask types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). If you tried to create a structure which conforms to `OptionSet`, you would notice that implementing `init(rawValue:)` initializer and `rawValue` property are required, example:

```
struct CustomOptions: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let easy = CustomOptions(rawValue: 0b00000001) // 1
    static let medium = CustomOptions(rawValue: 0b00000010) // 2
    static let hard = CustomOptions(rawValue: 0b00000011) // 3
    static let unfair = CustomOptions(rawValue: 0b00000100) // 4
}

let myOption = CustomOptions.medium
print(myOption) // CustomOptions(rawValue: 2)
```

<sub>Note that the `rawValues` usually are unique powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and so forth), but I just made them 1, 2, 3 and 4 for the purpose of the simplicity.</sub>

Because the options have raw values, you will be able to call the option without even the need of mentioning what's the struct, consider the following:

```
func doSomething(param: CustomOptions) {
    // ...
}

// you don't have to: doSomething(param: CustomOptions.medium)
// instead, you could call it like this:
doSomething(param: CustomOptions.medium)
```

Thus:

```
sender.setTitle("title", for: .normal)
```

**Enum VS Structure conforming to OptionSet**

But wait! why to use a structure that conforming to a `OptionSet` protocol instead of an enum?

In addition to what mentioned related to the difference between the used programming languages, enum is a representation for a *single value one at a time*, but OptionSet structure could be a representation for *combined values in a single value*, sound confusing? consider the following:

```
let combinedOption: CustomOptions = [.easy, .medium]
print(combinedOption) // CustomOptions(rawValue: 3)
```

At the first look, `[.easy, .medium]` might be tricky which looks like an array, but it is not! actually it is a single `CustomOptions` instance which is a combination (summation) of `easy` and `medium` options.

Thus:

```
sender.setTitle("title", for: [.normal, .disabled])
```

> Why are the "constants" for UIStateControl defined with "var" and not
>   "let?"

It could be related to how the representation of the bridged Objective-C enumeration cases should be, however, if you would try to:

```
UIControlState.normal = 3
```

You should obviously get the error of:

[image]

which means that it has been declared (Objective-C) as a *readonly* property.

Comment: Thanks for explainination did you know why `static var normal: UIControlState` ? instead of `let`

Comment: See [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399384/why-is-uicontrolstate-a-struct-and-not-an-enum/46405114#comment79767538_46399384); the fact that `UIControlState` is defined in Obj-C has nothing to with why it's not imported into Swift as an `enum`. It's purely because `UIControlState` is fundamentally not an `enum`.